# Anybody did somethinig like "alternative hotkey packs" for emacs?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm sure that almost everybody configured emacs in some way or another, but how many people shared their configurations, and where can I get them? I'm interested in something like starter packs, in things that make keyboard hotkeys less painful for newcomers.

Comment: There is lots of shared Emacs configuration on [github](https://github.com/search?l=Emacs+Lisp&q=emacs+configuration&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: @Nsukami_ know of one that looks like one described here http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18803/ ?

Comment: No I don't. I'm afraid, you'll have to dig and pick what is interested for you to build your configuration.

Comment: You will find lots of such on [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/), too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of a handful of modes and distributions that are along these lines, though ultimately I tuned my own bindings based on my usage.

Emacs itself has [CUA mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html), which makes many keybindings more like newer editors.  There's also [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs), which, among other things, includes keybindings that are more like Vim.  [better-defaults](https://github.com/technomancy/better-defaults) alters the behavior of certain keybindings, rather than the bindings themselves.  If you're focused on RSI issues, [ergomacs-mode](http://ergoemacs.github.io/) might be worth a look.

If you want to tune any of these further for your specific use case, I highly recommend checking out [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra).